# Performance difference between setting frame.origin vs CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, cocoa-touch, position

I have a grid-like thumbnail scroll view where I am firstly initializing all thumbnails and then setting its frame with:

```
thumbnail.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

then later on `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`, repositioning these thumbnails with:

```
thumbnail.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(posX, posY);
```

although when checking the position after the method above:

```
NSLog(@"thumbnail frame x: %f", thumbnail.frame.origin.x);
```

it will return the position including the transform operated and not `0,0`

Is there is a real benefit on using `transform` instead setting a new `frame` for an `UIView` as a reposition purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main benefit is that you can use more types of Affine Transformations, like

- `CGAffineTransformTranslate`
- `CGAffineTransformScale`
- `CGAffineTransformRotate`
- `CGAffineTransformInvert`
- `CGAffineTransformConcat`

but frame struct only sets the frame.

**Other notes:**

1) In performance reasons assuming that `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(posX, posY)` changes only `center` property it is loos like it should work faster than changing the `frame` property but who knows. So for reposition purposes I would use this way or changing the `center` property.

2) In contrast of `CALayer`'s `transform` the `UIView`'s `transform` changes real position of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Using the translation transform will move (translate) the view in the transformed perspective. That is, uf you first rotate the view, and then translates it, it will move in the direction relative to the rotation. For a simple reordering, I would suggest changing the `center` property instead. This way, you can still use the `frame` property in a meaningful way.